# How to filter records form mySQL using PHP and Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs

I have some records stored in mysql db. I want to retrieve the records using php and then display based on the users filters like price range, type etc...

This should happen as soon as user click on the filtering criteria (there will not be any submit button to apply the filter).

Your inputs will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Search something up about `PDO` and `SQL`

Answer (score 0):

You can develop it in 3 steps:

1. set up ng-click on 'filter' click
2. send an request for php and retrieve records
3. update scope variable after that and be sure you configured filter in attributes

here is:

[live preview](http://codepen.io/icrosil/pen/vOoqMR/)

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="example">
      <table>
          <thead>
              <th ng-click="customOrder('value')">
                  <a href="#">digits</a>
              </th>
              <th ng-click="customOrder('text')">
                  <a href="#">owners</a>
              </th>
          </thead>
          <tr ng-repeat="value in a_response | orderBy:orderMe">
              <td>{{value.value}}</td>
              <td>{{value.text}}</td>
          </tr>
      </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('example', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.a_response = [{
        value: 2,
        text: 'Ivan'
    }, {
        value: 3,
        text: 'Jack'
    },{
        value: 'text',
        text: 'Stack'
    }, {
        value: 1,
        text: 'Lack'
    }];
    $scope.orderMe = 'value';
    $scope.customOrder = function(ordering) {
        //TODO php request and a_resposne updating
        $scope.orderMe = ordering;
    };
}]);
```

hope i helped.

Comment: Thanks Illia for your response. Can you please elaborate a bit with pseudo code if possible.

Comment: This codepen might please you, here:
[a link](http://codepen.io/icrosil/pen/vOoqMR)
click on headers and filters would work

Comment: Thanks it really helped. Should I invoke my php code to populate $scope.a_response?(currently its static json)

Comment: You can call ajax get request from angular with $http service to your server and server should return some json, which change $scope.a_response. I`ve updated codepen with $http request.